# DataStax where condition on Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, datastax, cassandra-2.0

I am new to Spark. I am trying to do simple computation using Spark with Cassandra. if I add where condition (where("id=?", 5)) , I am getting below mentioned exception. if don't add where condition , I am not getting exception . But, It is taking more time to process, though the database has only 4 records in table.  Id is partition key in products table.

> Cassandra 2.1.11 Spark - 2.0.1-hadoop2.7 Java 1.8

How to add where condition ?

```
    SparkConf conf = initSparkContext();
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<Product> productRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("java_api", "products", Product.class).where("id=?", 5);
    List<Product> productList = productRDD.collect();
    for(Product product: productList) {
        System.out.println(" product = "+product);
    }
```

### Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--Spark Cassandra Connector-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

### Exception

```
6/11/15 13:44:34 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task ID 0
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "id", "name", "parents" FROM "java_api"."products" WHERE token("id") > -1732598212583841281 AND token("id") <= -1668034862038885205 AND id=? ALLOW FILTERING: id cannot be restricted by more than one relation if it includes an Equal
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.createStatement(CassandraRDD.scala:310)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraRDD.scala:317)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraRDD.scala:338)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD$$anonfun$13.apply(CassandraRDD.scala:338)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:10)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.foreach(CountingIterator.scala:4)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.to(CountingIterator.scala:4)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.toBuffer(CountingIterator.scala:4)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.toArray(CountingIterator.scala:4)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1080)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1080)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: id cannot be restricted by more than one relation if it includes an Equal
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:256)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:91)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.PreparedStatementCache$.prepareStatement(PreparedStatementCache.scala:45)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:28)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.createStatement(CassandraRDD.scala:293)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: id cannot be restricted by more than one relation if it includes an Equal
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:97)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$1.apply(SessionManager.java:156)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$1.apply(SessionManager.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$1.apply(Futures.java:720)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:859)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You've said that you are using Spark - 2.0.1-hadoop2.7 but your dependecies in pom.xml file are having 1.0.0 version. For Spark 2.0.1 your pom should be like below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
```

And spark code to read from Cassandra should be like

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .appName("SparkCassandraApp")
              .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:C:/temp")
              .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
              .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
              .master("local[*]")
              .getOrCreate();

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

JavaRDD<Product> productRDD = javaFunctions(jsc).cassandraTable("java_api", "products", CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(Product.class)).where("id=?", 5);
productRDD.foreach(data -> {
            System.out.println(data.getId());
            System.out.println(data.getName());
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. could you please suggest which version will be suitable for blow dependency as well.   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
if I increase to 1.4.0 , that version doesn't have CassandraJavaUtil class.

Comment: If you want to use Cassandra connector 1.4 then you can use spark 1.4. You can check Version Compatibility at https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector.  Some classes/methods will not be available in old connector jar and you have to modify your code accordingly.